# Using python class variable vs instance variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python. I'm trying to create a configuration class with required validators. In below code snippet, accessing variable 'a' using python class and instance of class is returning a different value. Whether this is a proper design or should i initialise var 'a' only in the class constructor and do validation in the setter method.

```
class IntField:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError('expecting integer')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

class DefaultConfig:
    a = IntField()

    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 2

print(DefaultConfig.a)
print(DefaultConfig().a)
```

output:

```
<__main__.IntField object at 0x10c34b550>
2
```

Comment: @Netwave Then how to set var a to 2?

Comment: As a descriptor, an instance of `IntField` is *intended* to be assigned to a class attribute, not an instance attribute. Your code is behaving as it should; you don't have any particular reason to access the class attribute directly, despite it being syntactically legal to do so.

Comment: @Netwave As chepner points out, it has to be a class attribute to function.

Comment: @chepner I agree it's working as expected. I just want to know whether it's right way to do it.

Comment: IMO, this is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just want to know whether it's right way to do it

Rather asking for opinion only answer, by I will try to be as objective as I can.

Your code behaves as expected as long as instances attributes are processed:

```
>>> c = DefaultConfig()
>>> c.a = 'foo'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#88>", line 1, in <module>
    c.a = 'foo'
  File "<pyshell#83>", line 10, in __set__
    raise ValueError('expecting integer')
ValueError: expecting integer
>>> c.a = 4
>>> c.a
4
```

When inspecting `DefaultConfig.a`, the `__get__` function is still used with `instance=None`. So you can choose one of 2 possible ways:

- be *transparent* and show what the attribute actually is (what you currently do)
- insist on the descriptor magic and return the default value (here 2).

For that latter way, code could become:

```
class IntField:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None:
            return getattr(owner, '_default_' + self.name, self)
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]

    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if not isinstance(value, int):
            raise ValueError('expecting integer')
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

class DefaultConfig:
    a = IntField()
    _default_a = 2
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = self._default_a
```

The trick here is that *by convention*, the default value for an attribute `x` is expected to be `_default_x`.

In that case, you will get:

```
print(DefaultConfig.a)
2
```

Comment: Good answer. You could probably omit setting the defaults in `__init__` if you adjusted `__get__` to always look for the default value as a fallback.